# Child to Parent Relationship Null Managed Package

Tags: soql, managed-package, relationships

My attempt to query a Child to Parent relationship ('__r') within a managed package is returning null. I've inserted the objects as below:

```
ns__Parent__c parent = new ns__Parent__c(ns__First_Name__c='Name',ns__Last_Name__c='Name',ns__Email__c='email@test.com');
insert parent;
ns__Child__c child = new ns__Child__c(ns__Parent__c=parent.Id,ns__Status__c='Pending');
insert child;
```

Running `child.ns__Parent__c` returns the id of the parent object, however, running `child.ns__Parent__r.Id` and `child.ns__Parent__r.ns__First_Name__c` returns null.

I've made sure the name of the relationship is correct by using:

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = Schema.sObjectType.ns__Child__c.fields.ns__Parent__c;
System.debug(f.getRelationshipName()); // returns ns__Parent__r
```

Can anyone explain why this happens and how I can query the relationship correctly?

**EDIT:**
I am attempting to run this query under a Guest Site User profile that I have given access (CRUD, and have tried View All and Modify All) to both parent and child objects, as well as all of their fields.

Comment: What exactly is your question? It sounds like `ns__Parent__c` works? Why would you want to use `ns__Parent__r.Id`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Hello-- I'm trying to retrieve other fields within the relationship as well, such as `ns__First_Name__c` or `ns__Email__c` from the parent. However, the entire relationship is returning null-- I'm wondering why this is happening and how to query correctly if I am executing it wrong

Comment: Are you able to view the parent object? It could be a permissions issue. Try to view it in the UI and see what you get.

Comment: Forgot to add it to my initial post-- I'm attempting to query this relationship as a Guest Site User profile which I have given access to the objects and fields. I've checked .isAccessible(), .isUpdateable(), .isCreateable() for the parent object, the child object, and the related desired fields and all returns 'true.' However .isUpdateable() returns false for the master-detail relationship field.  I don't believe this should cause issues though, would it?

Comment: Just created a test visual force page and set it as my site's active home page and I was able to view both child and parent objects as well.

Comment: Maybe stating your class as `public without sharing class` would help